# authenticate to SharePoint through OKTA from back-end service

Tags: sharepoint, saml, okta, okta-api

I have a need to programmatically connect to a customer's SharePoint server that uses OKTA for authentication.  I saw this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35233948) which looked promising, but cannot seem to get a valid session cookie back from OKTA.

I can successfully call the /api/v1/authn endpoint and get back a sessionToken, but when I turn around and call /api/v1/sessions?additionalFields=cookieToken with that session token, I always received a 403 - Forbidden, with the following json:

```
{ 
"errorCode": "E0000005", 
"errorSummary": "Invalid Session", 
"errorLink": "E0000005", 
"errorId": "oaew0udr2ElRfCnZvBFt075SA", 
"errorCauses": [] 
}
```

Assuming I can get this resolved, I'm not sure of the URL I should call with the cookieToken.  Is the url an OKTA endpoint that will redirect to SharePoint or is it an SharePoint endpoint that will setup the session with the cookie?

**Update:**
I am able to call this okta endpoint -> /api/v1/sessions?additionalFields=cookieToken with my user credentials as json

```
{ 
"username": "user@email.com",
"password": "P@ssw0rd"
}
```

And am able to retrieve a one-time cookie token that can be used with this link to start a SAML session in a browser:

```
https://[mydomain].okta.com/login/sessionCookieRedirect?redirectUrl=[sharepoint site url]&token=[cookie token]
```

That works in a browser, the user is automatically authenticated and ends up in SharePoint.  However, it seems that this session "setup" is at least partly achieved through javascript as executing the same link in a programmatic HTTP client (such as Apache HTTP Client) does not work.  The http client is sent through a couple of redirects and ends up in the SharePoint site, but the user is not authenticated.  The response is 403 - Forbidden with the following headers:

403 - FORBIDDEN

```
Content-Type -> text/plain; charset=utf-8
Server -> Microsoft-IIS/8.5
X-SharePointHealthScore -> 0
SPRequestGuid -> 0ecd7b9d-c346-9081-cac4-43e41f3b159a
request-id -> 0ecd7b9d-c346-9081-cac4-43e41f3b159a
X-Forms_Based_Auth_Required -> https://[sharepoint site]/_login/autosignin.aspx?ReturnUrl=/_layouts/15/error.aspx
X-Forms_Based_Auth_Return_Url -> https://[sharepoint site]/_layouts/15/error.aspx
X-MSDAVEXT_Error -> 917656; Access denied. Before opening files in this location, you must first browse to the web site and select the option to login automatically.
X-Powered-By -> ASP.NET
MicrosoftSharePointTeamServices -> 15.0.0.4709
X-Content-Type-Options -> nosniff
X-MS-InvokeApp -> 1; RequireReadOnly
Date -> Fri, 13 May 2016 15:02:38 GMT
Content-Length -> 13
```

I'm starting to wonder if this is a lost cause, that OKTA or SharePoint doesn't support programmatic authentication via SAML.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible.

Here is what I did.
1) Get your sessionToken from Okta. You'll need an okta authorization token for that.

2) Do a HttpGet(sharepointEmbeddedLink + "?onetimetoken=" + sessionToken)
   Also add this header: new BasicHeader(AUTHORIZATION, String.format("SSWS %s", OKTA_AUTHORIZATION_TOKEN);

3) Next you'll have to parse the html response and get the SAML Arguments: WRESULT, WCTX, WA

4) Next do this - take those 3 and create a string in this format "application/x-www-form-urlencoded". It will be something like this "wa=wsign1.0&wctx=somevalue&wresult=somevalue".

```
        byte[] out = theStringAbove.getBytes;
        int length = out.length;

        URL url = new URL("https://login.microsoftonline.com/login.srf");
        URLConnection con = url.openConnection();
        HttpURLConnection http = (HttpURLConnection) con;

        http.setRequestMethod("POST"); // PUT is another valid option
        http.setDoOutput(true);
        http.setInstanceFollowRedirects(true);
        http.setFixedLengthStreamingMode(length);
        http.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8");
        http.setRequestProperty("User-agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1) AppleWebKit/535.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/13.0.782.215 Safari/535.1");
        http.connect();
        http.getOutputStream().write(out);
```

5) You'll have the saml Token in the response. You'll have to parse an html file again.

6) You'll get the sharepoint siteUrl in step3 or 4 and do this next :)

```
    HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(siteUrl + "_forms/default.aspx?wa=wsignin1.0");
    byte[] utf8TokenStringBytes = ("t=" + samlToken).getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
    HttpEntity entity = new ByteArrayEntity(utf8TokenStringBytes);
    httpPost.setEntity(entity);
    httpPost.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8");
    httpPost.setHeader("User-agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1) AppleWebKit/535.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/13.0.782.215 Safari/535.1");

    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpPost, httpContext);
```

If everyting is ok, you'll have some cookie headers that you can use :D